# Generate MySQL Inserts with changes column names

Tags: mysql, migration, phpmyadmin

I need to migrate from my old user DB, to a new one.... but luckily the value of the password and salt fields are the same on both, but the column name are different (on old table:user passhash->secret, on new table:newuser password->salt)

How do I generate an insert dump from my existing users-data? Whenever I do something like

```
SELECT id,
  username,
LOWER(username) AS username_canonical,
  email,
  LOWER(email) AS email_canonical,
  passhash AS 'password',
  secret AS salt,
  1 AS enabled,
   'a:0:{}' AS roles,
   0 AS credentials_expired,
   0 AS expired,
   0 AS locked,
   uploaded,
   downloaded,
   torrent_pass,
   0 AS torrent_pass_version
FROM
  temp2.users AS fos_user
WHERE enabled = 'yes' ;
```

I can see the values correctly listed in phpMyAdmin...but when I export the results, I see inserts in the old structure:

```
INSERT INTO `fos_user` (`id`, `username`, `username`, `email`, 
    `email`, `passhash`, `secret`, `enabled`, `a:0:{}`, 
    `credentials_expired`, `expired`, `locked`, `uploaded`, 
    `downloaded`, `torrent_pass`, `torrent_pass_version`) 
VALUES....
```

Comment: Be more specific about this :on old table:user passhash->secret, on new table:newuser password->salt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the INSERT and SELECT at the same time with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `fos_users` (username, password, salt ...)
SELECT LOWER(username), passhash, secret, ...
FROM users;
```

Of course this assumes that you can have the old dataset in the new database, at least temporarily...

Comment: OP seems to know why the query generated has table name as alias name but the same is not applied in case of column names. And how to achieve it for column names too?

Answer (score 1):

If you export the table with the phpAdmin GUI , it will use the original schema of the table. In order to export it with your desired schema use the SELECT INTO file syntax : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html